# javaで文字列に￥が入っているか調べたい

Tags: java

javaで文字列に￥が入っているか調べたかったので

```
if(str.equals("￥")){
       ～
}
```

としたところ、文字リテラルが閉じられていませんとコンパイルエラーになりました。
どう書けばいいのでしょうか。

※このサイトでは￥が全角になっていますが、本当は半角です。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

便宜上、本回答でも全角の￥を用います。

- equalsメソッドは「文字列が同じであるか」を調べるメソッドですので、 **含まれている**には適しません。
- 含まれているかを調べるにはcontainsメソッドを使います
- Javaでは￥はエスケープ文字と呼ばれ、 **後ろに続く文字と合わせることで** 特殊な文字列を意味する記号となります。
- ￥そのものを示す場合は ￥￥ と2つ並べます。

Comment: ここで文字リテラルが閉じられていないと怒られるのは従って，￥" でひとまとまりとして解釈されるためですね．